# Shorting css when values are the same

Tags: css

How to short css if values are the same?
For example: how to unite this into one string (with one `auto!important`)?

```css
*{width: auto!important}  
*{height: auto!important}
```

It seems that I have seen such possibility (as a novelty) but can't find.

Comment: you can't: you may just shorten the code with a single declaration `*{width: ...; height: ...; }`

Comment: But I saw some new feature to short css (seems, added in 2019).

Comment: where did you see it?

Comment: I don't remember exactly((( But it was only about new features (css, js).

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I remember that it was about `div a{width: auto}, div p{width: auto}, div img{width: auto}`. A link to this is also needed.

Comment: I think you are talking about `:any()` (or `:matches()`) which can group selectors but not the values of the properties

Answer (score 1):

You can short declaration to one:

```
*{
width: auto!important;
height: auto!important
}
```

and you can short the value to one using css custom variable
so every time you wanna change the value  do it from one place:

```
:root{
--foo:auto!important;
}

*{
width:var(--foo);
height: var(--foo);
}
```

Comment: Good, but I want something like `*{width, height: auto!important}`.

Comment: this syntax not familiar to me even it exist you should to wait to be supported in the major browsers

Comment: Can it work in selectors? `nth-of-type(n + var(--gg)){float: left}`

Comment: I think nesting function not allowed even you try : `nth-of-type((2)){float: left}`

Comment: but this allowed with `SASS` : $number:2;
p:nth-of-type(#{$number}){
  color:red;
}