# Reduce css code when only changing image location

Tags: css

We have a growing css file with what seems like a lot of unnecessary duplication and I would like to know if there is some way to reduce this

```
.upsidedownsmile::before {
    mask: url(/public/img/svg/emoji-smile-upside-down.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-mask: url(/public/img/svg/emoji-smile-upside-down.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.people::before {
    mask: url(/public/img/svg/people.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-mask: url(/public/img/svg/people.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

Essentiall whats happening is we are just mapping some classes to some SVGs so that we can use them as icons through the website by calling

```
<i class="people"></i>
```

This all works well

The issue I think is that we could heavily reduce the amount of code.

The problem is I do not know of any way to reduce

Every class looks exactly the same and spans 100's of lines for seemingly no reason the only different between classes is the image location

I have tried to google some things like using css variables, inheritance.

Not very fruitful results I think the problem is I am not quite sure the terminology of what it is im looking for

Comment: Can you remove the second `-webkit` mask (shorthand) is pretty widely supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask  Also consider only using part of the shorthand for the image name `mask-image` and use a class to do the other parts perhaps.

Comment: Are you using or planning to use `<i>` for something besides icons (e. g. for italic text as it was intended)?

Comment: @Kosh no its only used for this purpose

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss some popular browsers (e.g. Edge/Chrome, Opera) still require the -webkit- prefix on mask so probably it can't be dropped as yet.

Comment: @AHaworth Ah, thanks I was testing locally with a MORE MODERN browser I see now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the i tag is used only for these types of settings you could do:

```
.upsidedownsmile {
    --b: url(/public/img/svg/emoji-smile-upside-down.svg);
}

.people {
    --b: url(/public/img/svg/people.svg);
}
i::before {
  mask: var(--b) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask: var(--b) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

That way you only need to add the url for each new class of i you introduce.

Comment: Not fully "only used for these types" as `<i>text things<i >` could also contain text - perhaps a span should be used despite some popular libraries promoting the idiomatic tag this way ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

Comment: provided this works(need to test) this could potentially reduce the code of the file by half I believe.

I think tho this may be what I was envisioning when I asked the question

Comment: I like this significantly better and it was a 40% decrease in lines. I will leave the question open for another day and if nothing better comes along will accept your answer

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think the OP conformed it was only used for these purposes in a comment. Also although the I tag was originally to denote italicised this is no longer the case.

Comment: I voted for this one since this should reduce the lines or at least make it more DRY and I would have trended toward this way given the limited scope available for review.  I had a CSS file someone put together once that was way out of control and I just started over instead of trying to figure out how 10,000+ lines of CSS was being used

Answer (score 0):

```
:root {
    --a: url(/public/img/svg/emoji-smile-upside-down.svg);
    --b: url(/public/img/svg/people.svg);
}
.upsidedownsmile::before {
    -webkit-mask: var(--a);
    mask: var(--a);
}
.people::before {
    -webkit-mask: var(--b);
    mask: var(--b);
}
i::before {
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-size: 50% 50%;
    mask-size: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Well no because the url would be different between the 2 classes

Comment: It seems that I have a question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297574

Comment: And how do you want to short it? Do you want a variable with `no-repeat 50% 50%`?

Comment: While this updated answer is not bad I feel the effort required is not outweighed by any benefits

Comment: You can short when values are the same. In your case, they aren't. You can request a new css feature here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues

Comment: The answer is updated. More shortening.

Comment: Not too bad going to leave open for a bit to see if we get any better answers

Comment: caniuse and my own tests, confirm that you still need WebKit, eg for Chrome.